# What does w3c : false under chrome options assert?

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, w3c, chrome-options

I am trying to run a protractor test, and had to include the following

```
chromeOptions: {
            args: ["--incognito"],
            w3c : false
        }
```

Had to set w3c flag to false, as it was affecting the keyboard events. But by doing so, the test is failing in other scenario. I want to know what is happening when w3c is set to false.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome or WebDriver. See [How to turn off w3c in chromedriver to address the error unknown command: Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C](//stackoverflow.com/a/56457780) for details on a similar case.